# Why does my HTML table row loses view state after dynamically adding rows to this table?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I have a simple HTML table like this:

```
<table id="table" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Column1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_someId" runat="server">
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lb_someId" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On every request I add dynamic rows **between** (`rowIdx = 1`) the existing rows like:

```
protected override void OnLoad( EventArgs e )
{
    base.OnLoad( e );

    if( !IsPostBack )
    {
        lb_someId.Text = "Some text";
    }

    int rowIdx = 1;

    foreach( ISomething something in GetSomethings() )
    {
        HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();
        tr.Cells.Add( CreateLabelCell( something ) );

        table.Rows.Insert( rowIdx++, tr );
    }
}
```

Now, I wonder, why my `lb_someId-Label` loses its text on a PostBack? I think it should not happen because it is a fixed control. It does not lose its text when I comment the `table.Rows.Insert( rowIdx++, tr );` line out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it's because you overwrite the row on which the label is placed

Comment: No, the row is still there, not overridden.

Comment: Ok. In that case as far as I know if you don't set a control's text or value in the ASPX markup, but do it in code-behind instead, then you have to set it every time the code-behind runs, including on postbacks. It's considered something you specified just for that request, not something to persist. It's not part of the ViewState. But you claim that if you do a postback, but don't add the new rows to the table then it keeps the label text anyway? That seems odd, which is what made me think you must be overwriting the row - you first write to index 1, which is the row index where the label is

Comment: No Sir, Text-Property of Label is usually persisted in ViewState, you dont have to set it on every request.

Comment: Ok well my mistake, it's a little while since I worked on WebForms regularly. So that takes us back to the original theory...you say " the row is still there, not overridden"...but how do you know, if the text has been removed? It won't really be visible. Did you check the generated page source to see what is there? I really think your code will overwrite the row containing the label, since that's the row at index 1, and index 1 is the first row you insert into.

Comment: I very simplified my code in this example. In reality there are more columns (with fixed text) in that last row, thats why I know its not overriden :)

Comment: Ok I think maybe I understand. I ran a simplified version myself on my machine. The insert doesn't overwrite the existing row, but it does move its position. I think maybe on postback because you change the position of the row in which the label exists, then it loses its viewstate. In your example, if you change `int rowIdx = 1;` to `int rowIdx = 2;` so that the inserting starts after the current row, and thus doesn't move that row's position, then you don't have this problem.

Comment: Yep, thats probably the problem. I just wonder why it is like that. ViewState usually works with the IDs of the controls and the ID of the last row is fixed as well. Hmm...

Comment: It's a strange one. You're not moving the label though, you're moving an ancestor element (the table row) which also is a HTML control rather than an ASPX control, I don't know if that's a factor in how it deals with viewstate - perhaps you could build the table using `<aspx:Table` style markup in case that makes any difference. Or possibly it just has to recreate the element in viewstate because it seems to be a different element, since it now occupies a different place in the DOM. We can only experiement to try and work out what the logic must be.

Comment: When I put the last row outside the table in a div/other table it works. Will try it with asp:Table as well. Thanks so far.

Comment: Not working with asp:Table either.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the value of the label gets lost is because it is part of a table to which new rows are being added in the `OnLoad` event. At this point in the lifecycle dynamically added controls are not being tracked anymore. The table tracks its viewstate as a whole, including some info about the label. If the label was outside of the table, there wouldn't have been a problem. See [MSDN: Understanding ASP.NET View State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

Move the code to `OnInit`.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{   
    base.OnInit(e);

    if( !IsPostBack )
    {
        lb_someId.Text = "Some text";
    }

    int rowIdx = 1;

    foreach( ISomething something in GetSomethings() )
    {
        HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();
        tr.Cells.Add( CreateLabelCell( something ) );

        table.Rows.Insert( rowIdx++, tr );
    }
}
```

Alternativelly, only moving the `foreach` loop to `OnInit` would suffice.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if( !IsPostBack )
    {
        lb_someId.Text = "Some text";
    }
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{   
    base.OnInit(e);

    int rowIdx = 1;

    foreach( ISomething something in GetSomethings() )
    {
        HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();
        tr.Cells.Add( new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = something } );

        table.Rows.Insert( rowIdx++, tr );
    } 
}
```